# Assuming good faith vs answering the (in my opinion) actual underlying intent of a question

Tags: discussion

Some extended conversation going on about this question:

**[Did Einstein say this about Jesus?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/38024/did-einstein-say-this-about-jesus)**

On its face, this is a question about the accuracy of a quote. It was immediately answered by the original poster, with a citation that I'm going to assume is accurate. Answering your own question isn't against the rules, but it does raise the question about motivation:

Based on my experience, quotes like this are used all the time by Christians, in an effort to make arguments for their faith. So in a way, there is a second, underlying question: **"are Christians justified in using this Einstein quote to support their faith's claims about Jesus existence and deity?"** or, perhaps, **"was Einstein a Christian?**.

Can I post an answer to that (implied) underlying question, or would that be off-topic?

Comment: For this specific case, it might be worth mentioning that said answer does not support an idea of making Einstein's quote about religion, but rather explicitly puts it into the context of "was there a historical basis for scripture?"

Comment: @SeanDuggan While an argument about a historical basis for scripture is admittedly not the *entirety* of Christians' claims for their faith, it's certainly a major component. Interestingly, a second answer has appeared (and been highly upvoted) taking the approach I've asked about in this question.